# IBM MQ - Message reading & invoking down-line services transactional

Tags: transactions, jms, ibm-mq, message-queue, spring-jms

I am working on consumer for IBM MQ messages, I want to make each message processing transactional after reading with acknowledgement.

Once I read each message from IBM MQ - i need to invoke about 4 to 5 different rest services.  There will be approximately 1500 - 2000 inserts in different tables through services.

If any of the service fails for any reason, I want to roll back previous inserts happened in processing that particular message and leave message in Queue.

How can I achieve the same? I am quite new to IBM MQs/Jms

I am planning to do it by browsing through messages using

```
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = context.createBrowser(queue, "JMSCorrelationID='ID:c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'");
```

Answer (score 1):

If all these queues are on the same MQ Queue Manager, you should use 'local JMS transactions' for this. So create your IBM MQ JMS connection and make your session transacted (first argument is set to **true**):

```
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Note: The second argument is ignored in case the first argument is true.

Create your JMS queues and the receiver and then read your first message, for example:

```
Message msg = msgConsumer.receive(100);
```

This implicitly starts an MQ transaction on the first message received if there is no current transaction.

Next do your processing and if all goes well, call commit.

If not, rollback the transaction and you will see all rolled back messages again. So it could work something like this:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageConsumer msgConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination, null);
while( !isStopped() ) {

  try {

    Message msg = msgConsumer.receive(100);
    if( msg!=null ) { 
      ... call your REST services ...
      session.commit();
    }
    ... test for end condition ...
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    ... error handling ...
    session.rollback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the approach you suggested is transactional per message?

Comment: This won't deal with rolling back inserts from previous REST calls when a subsequent REST call fails. It will only deal with rolling back the message to the queue. If the message is redelivered then the original REST calls will be repeated potentially producing duplicates records in the database.

Comment: Got it. What options do I have to achieve functionality I was looking for?

Comment: Well, since REST is not a transactional API by definition, it won’t be builtin.

Comment: If, however, you have a chance to use JDBC instead of REST for your database access, you could use JTA and one transaction manage to combine JMS as well as JDBC transactions. See JMS's XAConnectionFactory and 'JTA'